# Theorem, Lemma etc numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems

I have problem for numbering my theorems and definition as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{myde}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{mydef}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{mydeg}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{myd}{Approach}[section]
\newtheorem{my}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{mydep}{Proof}
\newtheorem*{proof*}{Proof}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}

\begin{myde}
this is correct
\end{myde}

\begin{mydef}
this one should be Example 1.1.2
\end{mydef}

\begin{myde}
this one should be Conjecture 1.1.3
\end{myde}

\begin{mydeg}
this one should be Definition 1.1.4
\end{mydeg}

\begin{myde}
this one should be Conjecture 1.1.5
\end{myde}

\begin{my}
this one should be Theorem 1.1.6
\end{my}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your main problem here is in the understanding of `\newtheorem`. Since you're using [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), let's look at the documentation (specifically, section **3 Theorem numbering**):

> In addition to the two mandatory arguments, `\newtheorem` has two mutually
>   exclusive optional arguments. These govern the sequencing and hierarchy of
>   the numbering. The numbering mechanism can be thought of this way:
>
> ```
> \newtheorem{<env name>}{<text>}[<parent counter>]
> \newtheorem{<env name>}[<shared counter>]{<text>}
> ```
>
> The `<parent counter>` is comparable to `\numberwithin`; that is, numbering will
>   restart whenever that sectional level is encountered. If a `<shared counter>` is
>   specified, numbering will progress sequentially for all theorem elements using
>   this counter.

You should be using the second version if you want a numbering scheme that shares the same counter. But you've been using the first, which creates a unique counter for every theorem style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{myde}{Conjecture}[section]% Conjecture is numbered within \section
\newtheorem{mydef}[myde]{Example}% Example uses myde's counter
\newtheorem{mydeg}[myde]{Definition}% Definition uses myde's counter
\newtheorem{my}[myde]{Theorem}% Theorem uses myde's counter
\newtheorem{myd}[myde]{Approach}% Approach uses myde's counter
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}% Lemma uses myde's counter
\newtheorem{corollary}[myde]{Corollary}% Corollary uses myde's counter

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}

\begin{myde}
this is correct
\end{myde}

\begin{mydef}
this one should be Example 1.1.2
\end{mydef}

\begin{myde}
this one should be Conjecture 1.1.3
\end{myde}

\begin{mydeg}
this one should be Definition 1.1.4
\end{mydeg}

\begin{myde}
this one should be Conjecture 1.1.5
\end{myde}

\begin{my}
this one should be Theorem 1.1.6
\end{my}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! Great explanation. I manage to play around with it.