# Labeling with 2 tiers in main text and 3 tiers in appendix

Tags: formatting

I'm writing some notes, and I'd like to have a different labeling convention in the appendices than in the main text. In the main text I'd like to label things with 2 tiers (e.g., Theorem 3.2) while in the appendix I'd like to label them with 3 tiers (e.g., Theorem A.1.5). Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45358/121799), i.e. try `\numberwithin`. If this fails, you may want to provide more context, e.g. an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45358/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{mythm}{Theorem}[section] 

\begin{document}
\section{Eucalyptus trees}
\begin{mythm}
   Koalas love eucalyptus. 
\end{mythm}

\section{Marmots}
\begin{mythm}
   Koalas like marmots. 
\end{mythm}

\numberwithin{mythm}{subsection}
\appendix
\section{Activities}
\subsection{During daytime}
\begin{mythm}
   Koalas sleep a lot. 
\end{mythm}
\subsection{Hibernation}
\begin{mythm}
   Koalas don't hibernate. 
\end{mythm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful! As a quick followup, if I want to change the numbering for both Lemmas and Theorems (and other theorem environments), do I have to add lines
\numberwithin{theorem}{subsection}
and
\numberwithin{lemma}{subsection}
or is it possible to change the numberings for all environments with one command?

Comment: @AaronLandesman No, you can make counters follow a master counter, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335289/121799) and perhaps also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430733/121799).